# bash Array is not updated with the new assignment

Tags: arrays, bash

Below is the code that i tried

```
app+=(0)
top+=(1 2 3 4 5)
for i in ${app[@]}
do
echo $i th time
app=${top[@]}
done
```

the output

```
(09:01:12)-> ./loop.sh



0 th time
```

please advice why cant the new value is updated and
only once the code is running

Comment: Your for loop loops over the values in app. There is only one value in app...

Comment: but at the end i modified the app array

Comment: What do you think should happen?

Comment: I thought the script would run 6 times (including top array's assignment)

Comment: In the `for` loop, `${app[@]}` is expanded only once, so you can alter `app` as much as you like, but it will not affect the list that the `for` loop is working on.  BTW, many languages do not allow you to alter a list that you are iterating over.

Comment: Also, `app=${top[@]}` does not append to the array, it replaces the first element with all of the elements of `top` stuck together as a single string. I think you want `app+=("${top[@]}")`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to do but you can modify this to suit your needs:

```
app+=(0)
top+=(1 2 3 4 5)
for ((i=0; i<${#app[@]};++i)); do
    echo "$i" th time, "${app[i]}" element
    app=(${top[@]})
done
```

Gives:

```
0 th time, 0 element
1 th time, 2 element
2 th time, 3 element
3 th time, 4 element
4 th time, 5 element
```

Comment: That's really ugly style: Ugly `[`, unquoted expansions, `while` loop instead of a `for` loop...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, thanks! do you see any problems now?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `${app[@]}` is expanded **only once**, so it makes no different from `for i in 0`. You can't modify the loop range once the loop has started. Your best bet could be using some other tricks like

```
ind=0
loop() {
    eval $1=${app[$ind]}
    (( ind++ ))
    return 0
}

while loop i
do
    # Now you can modify $app
done
```

But at last, it's not recommended to attempt to change the loop range during it.

Comment: there are many normal/simple ways of looping over an array as it grows, this is very unnecessary. The use of eval is totally unjustified.